# Returning an ArrayList of any type

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have some `ArrayList`s declared. Some of them are `ArrayList<Integer>` and other are `ArrayList<Double>`.

I want to get them from another class, so I wrote a method:

```
private ArrayList<Double> list1, list2;
private ArrayList<Integer> list3;

    public ArrayList getList(String nameOfList){
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
        if(nameOfList.equals("list1")) myList = list1;
        else if(nameOfList.equals("list2")) myList = list2;
        else if(nameOfList.equals("list3")) myList = list3;
        return myList;
    }
```

This compiles, but throws me some warnings:

```
*ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized* in the method above, and *Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<? extends Number>* when calling the method from here:

    XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(data.getList("list1"), data.getList("list2"), "My chart");

where SimpleXYSeries is a chart whose constructor expects to be getting **(List<? extends Number>, List<? extends Number>, String)**.
```

Which is the right way to do what I'm intending to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use multiple methods instead of one god method.**

This is poor design to have one `getList` method that uses a `String` to select a member.  Instead, there should be multiple methods - one for each list.  Then each method can return the type appropriate to its list.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the design is poor and should be reconsidered.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to have separate getters for each of the lists.

If you really want to stick to the single getter approach, you can adjust your method signature (and implementation accordingly) to

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> getList( String nameOfList )
```

and explicitly specify `<T>` when calling the method.

Or pass a `Class<T>` as well, as suggested by Johan

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try the following signature

```
public <T> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use one getter per field.

```
public List<String> getList1() { return list1; }
public List<String> getList2() { return list2; }
public List<Integer> getList3() { return list3; }

XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(data.getList1(), data.getList2(), "My chart");
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you use Java5. You can declare the method with generics.

```
public ArrayList<? extends Object> getList(String nameOfList) {
    ArrayList<? extends Object> myList = null;
    if (nameOfList.equals("list1"))
        myList = list1;
    else if (nameOfList.equals("list2"))
        myList = list2;
    else if (nameOfList.equals("list3"))
        myList = list3;
    return myList;
}
```

But I wouldn't suggest this design. you should have each method for getting each list.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a parametrized List, as the compiler says. In your case, you can use the supertype of `Integer` and `Double` - `Number`, so you method signature will look like 
   `public ArrayList<Number> getList(String nameOfList)`

Better still, do not use a concrete List implementation as your return type if do not have very good reason to do so - use the common interface of all lists - `List`, changing the signature to
   `public List<Number> getList(String nameOfList)`

The reason or the principle behind this advice is the [**Dependency inversion principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), the 'D' of the [**SOLID principles of software design**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Answer (score 1):

Not the best recommendation, but given your situation I would change my method to:

```
public ArrayList<? extends Number> getList(String nameOfList){
    ArrayList<? extends Number> myList = new ArrayList<Number>();
    if(nameOfList.equals("list1")) myList = list1;
    else if(nameOfList.equals("list2")) myList = list2;
    else if(nameOfList.equals("list3")) myList = list3;
    return myList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `ArrayList<Number>` for holding both Double and Integer, since [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is the parent class of both Double and Integer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like way

```
public ArrayList<? extends Object> getList(String nameOfList){

     if(nameOfList.equals("list1")) return list1;

     if(nameOfList.equals("list2")) return list2;

     return list3;    
}
```